# MySQL (Windows10) FULLTEXT searching with MyISAM tables not working

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a problem which I have been able to recreate with two very simple tables. The tables were defined as follows:

```
create table Temp_Table_MyISAM(  
  id  INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  code VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,  
  name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,    
  PRIMARY KEY (id),  
  KEY (code),  
  FULLTEXT (name)  
) ENGINE = MYISAM;  


create table Temp_Table_InnoDB(  
  id  INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  code VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,  
  name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (id),  
  KEY (code),  
  FULLTEXT (name)  
);
```

Each table has two rows, as can be seen from the result of the following two queries:

**select * from Temp_Table_MyISAM;**

```
 +----+---------+----------------+  
 | id | code    | name           |  
 +----+---------+----------------+  
 |  1 | AC-7865 | 38 NORTHRIDGE  |  
 |  2 | DE-3514 | POLARIS VENTRI |  
 +----+---------+----------------+
```

**select * from Temp_Table_InnoDB;**

```
 +----+---------+----------------+  
 | id | code    | name           |  
 +----+---------+----------------+  
 |  1 | AC-7865 | 38 NORTHRIDGE  |  
 |  2 | DE-3514 | POLARIS VENTRI |  
 +----+---------+----------------+
```

When I do a FULLTEXT search on the MyISAM table, I don't get any hits

> MariaDB [stackoverflow]> **SELECT name, code FROM Temp_Table_MyISAM
>   WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('38');**
>   Empty set (0.00 sec)
>
> MariaDB [stackoverflow]> **SELECT name, code FROM Temp_Table_MyISAM
>   WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('POLARIS');**
>   Empty set (0.00 sec)

When I do a FULLTEXT search on the InnoDB table, I get a hit only when the pattern to be matched does not start with a numeric value

> MariaDB [stackoverflow]> **SELECT name, code FROM Temp_Table_InnoDB
>   WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('38');**
>   Empty set (0.00 sec)
>
> MariaDB [stackoverflow]> **SELECT name, code FROM Temp_Table_InnoDB
>   WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('POLARIS');**

```
+----------------+---------+  
| name           | code    |  
+----------------+---------+  
| POLARIS VENTRI | DE-3514 |  
+----------------+---------+
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest reading the [fulltext manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html). The very last paragraph covers your first problem, also conveniently extracted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25343355) (and many more similar questions). The second problem is covered 14 lines above this in that manual (the word "38" is too short to be included in the index), explained e.g. [in this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/76036) (and many more). But again, you should really read the manual, as there are more things to consider (e.g. stopword lists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 rules to watch out for in MyISAM's `FULLTEXT`:

- Text words shorter than `ft_min_word_len` (default 4 characters) will not be indexed.  ("38")
- Search words that show up in more 50% or more of the rows, will be ignored.  ("Polaris")
- "Stop words" in the text are not indexed.  ("the", "and", ...)

Since InnoDB now supports `FULLTEXT`, you should move to that engine.  (And the rules are different there.)