# Mysql Full Text Match Returns Bool Match but 0 Relevance

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, full-text-indexing, relevance

I'm having some behavior I've not experienced before with Mysql's full text indexing. The relevance for a search with `cell` comes back as 0 for all records. The `in boolean` result though verifies the term is present (and the `where` clause also).

```
select sum(char_length(concat(columns))), MATCH (columns) AGAINST ('+"cell"' IN BOOLEAN MODE), MATCH (columns) AGAINST ('"cell"'), id
from table
where MATCH (columns) AGAINST ('+"cell"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I checked the default stop word list, and verified I'm not using a custom list. What could be the reason for the `0` relevance and how can I correct it?

The content lengths vary greatly from `1717` characters up to `115905` so I wouldn't be surprised to see 4/115905 being ranked low (presuming it only occurred once). The 4/1717 I would expect to at least be a fraction though.. and this logic also assumes the term only appeared once. The term is present multiple times.

I read the manual entry as well and was thinking maybe this passage

> Relevance is computed based on the number of words in the row (document), the number of unique words in the row, **the total number of words in the collection**, and the number of rows that contain a particular word.

and was thinking maybe because `cell` is present in all the articles it nullified the result but that didn't match up with other tests I ran. For example `animal model` brings back relevance as I'd expect.

My full text index length is 1 character.

The table with the index is:

```
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
```

Comment: You are using MyISAM? For MyISAM, [Search words that show up in more 50% or more of the rows, will be ignored.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48431277) (in natural language mode)

Comment: @Solarflare Yes, the engine is `MyISAM` but that doesn't hold true for the `animal model` example. All the rows have that term... or am I misreading that?

Comment: Yes, I think you are misreading it. Terms that show up in >= 50% of rows will be ignored in natural language mode (so you get a score of 0/no search result if you would use that mode in `where`) but not in boolean mode (so you currently find them).