# How Mysql full text search relevances compute?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, database

How does MySQL compute the relevance of results of a full-text search? I know as it's documented:

> Relevance is computed based on the number of words in the row, the number of unique words in that row, the total number of words in the collection, and the number of documents (rows) that contain a particular word.

But how these parameters come into those numbers?

Comment: sounds like this SO question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237970/full-text-search-relevance-is-measured-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here there's the explain of the full-text algorithm http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_Algorithms#Full-text_Search

Comment: so it seams so complicated! I thought it has a simple answer!